# Is it possible to make the last column as a checkbox column in SWT table?

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I know we can create a table with a checkbox column in SWT using following code:

```
Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.CHECK)
```

e.g. Following is a SWT table with a checkbox column:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/images/tableViewer.gif

But the checkbox column is located at the first column, is it possible to "move" the checkbox to the last column when creating the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no simple way to do that. You can add a new column with images of checkboxes, as shown in this snippet:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet061FakedNativeCellEditor.java?view=markup

There is an open bug in Eclipse Bugzilla to provide a built-in solution for this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=285121

Comment: Thanks you! I will use the solution:  add a new column with images of checkboxes...

Answer (score 0):

You may instantiate the table using `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT`, but then you would have to do everything reversed on your table, because if you don't it will seem to be "mirrored".

Comment: It is mirrored. There is no other way?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not another way.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use `org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor` to do this. Table editor is used to add any control on top of the cell in the table.